# Confused about the use of @Remote in an EAR

Tags: dependency-injection, java-ee-6, ear, stateful-session-bean

Using NetBeans, I have successfully run the shopping-cart example presented in the Java EE 6 tutorial on the Oracle website. It's an EAR with two modules: an EJB module and an application client module. I have cut short some details of the code in order to focus on the confusions I am facing. Firstly, below is the code.

**The remote interface in the EJB module**

```
package cart.ejb;

import cart.util.BookException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Cart {
  public void initialize(String person) throws BookException;

  public void initialize(
     String person,
     String id) throws BookException;

  public void addBook(String title);

  public void removeBook(String title) throws BookException;

  public List<String> getContents();

  public void remove();
}
```

**The stateful session bean in the EJB module**

```
package cart.ejb;

import cart.util.BookException;
import cart.util.IdVerifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remove;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;


@Stateful
public class CartBean implements Cart {
  List<String> contents;
  String customerId;
  String customerName;

  public void initialize(String person) throws BookException {
   .................
  }

  public void initialize(
     String person,
     String id) throws BookException {
   .....................
  }

  public void addBook(String title) {
    contents.add(title);
  }

  public void removeBook(String title) throws BookException {
    .................
  }

  public List<String> getContents() {
    return contents;
  }

  @Remove()
  public void remove() {
    contents = null;
  }
}
```

**The client in the application client module**

```
package cart.client;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import cart.ejb.Cart;
import cart.util.BookException;


public class CartClient {
   @EJB
   private static Cart cart;

   public CartClient(String[] args) {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     CartClient client = new CartClient(args);
     client.doTest();
   }

   public void doTest() {
     ..................
   }
}
```

**Now my confusions begin!!**

**Confusion-1:** The tutorial says it is a remote client. But it is not! It is packaged as a module within the same EAR as the EJB module. Wouldn't @Local be more appropriate?

**Confusion-2:** If glassfish does consider it a remote communication between the client and the session bean, will the client's container supply a fake instance of the session bean (i.e. proxy) representing the actual instance of the session bean in the EJB container, just like in a "real" remote case? I mean, does remote mean remote, not matter what?

**Confusion-3:** I am thinking about creating a client in a non-EE environment and then getting it to communicate with the bean from outside that EAR, to get a taste of "real" remote. So, if I launch Eclipse and create a Java SE 7 client program by copying contents from the client in EAR, are these the changes I have to make?

Replace dependency injection

```
@EJB
private static Cart cart;
```

with JNDI

```
private static Cart cart = (Cart) InitialContext.lookup("java:global/cart/cart-ejb/CartBean/Cart");
```

and add the Cart interface's source code in the Java Standard Edition client project.

**Confusion-4:** I am unable to find the location of that EAR file. On NetBeans, I can see under cart there are two jar files. But, where is the EAR file? I deployed the project by directly opening it from **C:\glassfish-4.1.1\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\ejb\cart** with NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

1. @Local would be enough yes, apparently they were lazy with the demonstration and chose to package it all in one. Regardless, your deployment unit is the scope of you @Local interface, so 2 different EARS in the same container could not access each-others @Local interfaces
2. Yes and no: the outside behavior will be completely identical to a real remote case (with serialization and proxying of objects), but how this is really handled behind the scenes depends on the container implementation. To my knowledge most containers will leverage the fact that even though it's @Remote it is located in the same JVM so for example they will not make an actual remote socket connection.

3.

- You need the remote interfaces of your beans
- Configure glassfish to allow remote calls on a specific port with specific credentials
- Do a JNDI lookup against this setup

Comment: Specific port with special credentials? Would I need to do it if, instead of creating a Java SE client application, I simply took out the application client module from the EAR and ran as a stand-alone module in order to communicate with the EJB module which would be the only module in EAR after I took out the client?

Comment: No in that case you just need to make a portable JNDI lookup from the separated client app (a WAR will do just fine, you don't need an EAR for the client but make sure to package the remote interfaces into it preferably as a JAR lib)